# Default image editor GIMP not working with Kdenlive

Tags: kdenlive

I have installed Kdenlive version 20.04 and am trying to set GIMP as a clip editor, so in order to do that I am trying to supply the GIMP path:

```
/snap/bin/gimp
```

In the settings

```
-> configure kdenlive-> environment default application
```

does not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... not sure if this is the only way to do this as it does seem a little limiting.

Go to Ubuntu (if you are using Ubuntu) System Settings/Details then select Default Applications then Select GIMP as the default application for Photos.

Go back to Kdenlive Settings/Configure Kdenlive/Default Apps and make sure this path is set for image editing: /usr/bin/xdg-open.

Sorry if my answer is not what you were looking for but this is the only way I could get this right after about two hours of swearing and throwing things.